# How to modify a jQuery Mobile page before it's loaded?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a single page application in jQuery Mobile 1.4.0, with 4 pages. At start I want some chckboxes to be disabled by default.

This works:

```
$("#page3 .ui-checkbox").prop("disabled", true);
    $("#page3 .ui-checkbox").addClass("ui-disabled");
```

html

```
<div data-role="page" class="page3" id="page3" data-dom-cache="true">
```

document ready() isn't working... document on "pagecreate" works, but changes to page3 will be applied when navigating to page2....

**Update**
I tried this... seems to work. Is this good/bad ?

```
$(function()
{
    $(document).on("pagecreate", "#page3", function(e){
         $("#page3 .ui-checkbox").prop("disabled", true);
         $("#page3 .ui-checkbox").addClass("ui-disabled");
    });
```

Comment: Use `$(document).bind('pageinit')` instead of `$(document).ready()`

Comment: I can't. It will mess up other code... pageinit = pagecreate i guess?

Comment: you dont need to wrap `pagecreate` or any page event in `$(function(){});`

Comment: @Omar Moved it outside.. testing :)

Comment: View http://api.jquerymobile.com/category/events/ for a list of events

Comment: @Omar Sweet, works :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To disable/enable checkbox or radio, use `.checkboxradio()` functions. You dont need to add `ui-state-disabled`.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
  $(".selector").checkboxradio("disable");
  $(".selector").checkboxradio("enable");
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/9KRG5/)**

Comment: Didn't know you could have multiple pagecreate :) Now I do! Thanks!

Comment: @BakedInhalf you can bind `pagecreate` to specific pages.